# Blank value in the select instead of the value

Tags: html, angularjs

In my html I have the following markup

```
<div class="col-md-8">
                @*@Html.DropDownList("templateTypes", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TemplateTypes, new { @class = "form-control", ng_model = "currentTemplate.tmplType" })*@
                <select class="form-control" name="templateTypes" id="templateTypes"
                        ng-model="currentTemplate.tmplType" 
                        ng-options="t.value as t.text for t in templateTypes"></select>
            </div>
```

The tmplType is Byte in the model. Value and Text are strings. When I view my form, the select comes blank. If I select a different value (there are only 2 options), I can see that this value is going correctly into the database. However, the select option still shows blank after the form re-loads. What may be the problem here?

Comment: after reloading which value has your currentTemplate.tmplType ?

Comment: is `currentTemplate.tmplType == t.value`? Not sure if i understood you correctly, when 'tmplType is Byte' and 'Value and Text are strings' you have to parse one of them.

Comment: In the Google Chrome Developer tools I see the following:
$scope.currentTemplate.tmplType
1
$scope.templateTypes
[Object selected: true text: "Pass"value: "1"
So, the tmplType is 1 and the value is "1". I don't know why does it make a difference that the drop down shows blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. All I had to do was to change from commented code to string

// public TemplateTypes TmplType { get; set; }
        public string TmplType { get; set; }

and that works nicely now. I didn't need to do anything else, the conversion happens automatically into byte from the view model where it's now string.